# Connect with Twilio without using microphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip

I use Twilio to deliver audio messages with VOIP, and I don't require any voice input. But By default on the first call the system asks for Microphone access permission.

How to remove this permission accesss, I don't neeed it.

I'm on iOS and using Objective-c.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Programmable Voice SDK for iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios) is intended for two way voice communications and that's why it requires microphone access. I don't think you can achieve this delivery of audio messages without that permission.

Comment: Thank you, I'll stop trying, but I still think it should be a possibility